# Single key/keyword to invoke code formatter across all extensions?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

Is there a way to bind a single in visual mode, or a small word in ex mode that will invoke the code formatter for the active filetype? For example "ESC : fmt" or CTRL ALT F in visual mode, to invoke "ESC : Prettier" or "ESC : RustFmt" for javascript or rust code respectively.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for [`:h 'formatprg'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27formatprg%27):

```
'formatprg' 'fp'    string (default "")
            global or local to buffer |global-local|
    The name of an external program that will be used to format the lines
    selected with the |gq| operator.  The program must take the input on
    stdin and produce the output on stdout.  The Unix program "fmt" is
    such a program.
    If the 'formatexpr' option is not empty it will be used instead.
    Otherwise, if 'formatprg' option is an empty string, the internal
    format function will be used |C-indenting|.
```

You can set it to use an external formatting tool or the built-in mechanism.

Once you have set `formatprg` properly you can use `gq` as a command to format your code the same way you'd use `d` to delete it or `y` to yank it. For example `gqip` will format the current paragraph.

You can also use [`:h 'equalprg'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27equalprg%27) and the command `=`.

And as you want to have a different setting for each filetype, the best practice is to set it in a [ftplugin](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#ftplugin)

For example for javascript you could create a file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/javascript.vim` and put something like the following in it:

```
setlocal formatprg=prettier\ --stdin
```